# vision.OpticalFlow is not showing the video nor the value of the flow

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-cvst, opticalflow, vision

I am trying to see the velocity of an object by using Matlab so I came up with this code

```
reader = vision.VideoFileReader ('C:\folder1\objectsandflow.avi');
viewer = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer;
optical = vision.OpticalFlow;
optical.OutputValue = 'Horizontal and vertical components in complex form';
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer('Name','Motion Vector');

while isDone (reader)
I = step(reader);
of = step (optical, rgb2gray(I));
y = of .* conj(of);
step(viewThresh,y>mean(y(:)));
step(videoPlayer)
end
release(videoPlayer);
release(reader);
```

The problem is I cannot see either the values of the flow (I mean I am looking for the velocity of some objects and I can use Matlab for it, can I?), nor the video

At the same time I do not know whether this will work to calculate all the velocities of my objects in the case that this code can't, how can I calculate multiple velocities in Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in these two lines:

```
step(viewThresh,y>mean(y(:)));
step(videoPlayer)
```

Try replacing them with these:

```
viewThresh = y;
viewThresh(y < mean(y(:))) = 0;
step(videoPlayer, viewThresh);
```

You do not need the `step` method for thresholding `y`, because you are not using any objects. And when you call `step` on the `videoPlayer` object, you have to pass in the video frame you wish to display.

Comment: what I want is to know the speed of four objects in my video, so (according to what I have found) I need to use step or opticalflow but I still do not know how to see these speeds in the video,        I can sectorise my objects and count them but I do not know how or wht to do to see their speed                                         help help help

Comment: You can use `quiver` to visualize the flow vectors.